# Rendering handlebars Page Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am attempting to render a handlebars page and I am getting my 404 error and I am not sure why. It's almost as if it does not recognize the handlebars file. My file hierarchy looks like this:
[image]

I am calling the path with this section of the current page:

```
<p><a href="http://18.219.103.143:3000/admin-dashboard">Admin Login</a></p>
```

In the main js file, I am handling the `admin-dashboard` with this code:

```
app.get('/admin-dashboard', function(req,res){
  var context = {};
  res.render('adminDash', context);
});
```

`adminDash.handlebars` only contains:

```
<h1>Admin Page</h1>
```

View Engine:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I tried console.log and/or alert in the `app.get` function to debug but nothing printed to console. Might it be the way I am calling the `render()`? Not sure how to debug when I can't print statements. Does anything look obviously out of place?

Answer (score 0):

What view engine do you use and how have you set up it? If you use the default `hbs` then the suffix is `.hbs`

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Comment: My other handlebars pages work. This is the only one that doesn't work. Here is what I have: `app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3000);
app.use(express.static('public'));`

Comment: It looks like I resolved the issue by stopping the execution and restarting. Maybe the handlebars changes don't take affect until restarted?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install handlebars: `npm i express-handlebars`
2. Add code:

const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: 'hbs',
    runtimeOptions: {
        allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
        allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
    }
});
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', 'views');
```